# Installing RHEL to multiple-boot with Windows and two other Linux distributions

Tags: rhel, boot, partition, system-installation, swap

Alright, so I made an earlier attempt to install RHEL 7.2 with automatic partitioning, and it turned into a mess since I have 3 other operating systems installed (windows + 2 Debian based Linux distros), so this time I will try again with manual partitioning and I have a few questions...

**Question 1**

Do I need to setup a separate boot partition for RHEL or can it use the same boot partition as my Debian based Linux distros?

**Question 2**

Do I need to setup a separate swap partition for RHEL or can it use the same swap that I use with my other Linux distros?

If the answers to the above questions are no, and I can use the same boot/swap, will it automatically recognize them, or will I need to do something in order for it to recognize them?

Comment: If you hibernate, then you need a separate swap for each.

Comment: Really? That seems sorta odd since I'll only be using 1 operating system at a time....anyways, I did a search on recommended swap size and I got varying results....most said 1.5 of total ram if planning to hibernate....if planning to hibernate with 12gb ram do I really need an 18gb swap for each?

Comment: Yes, you do.   You cannot share swap space.

Comment: And I need an 18gb swap space for each?

Comment: If you are hibernating one, and then going into another, then you are using more than one at a time; Though only one is running. A lot of advice about swap size is wrong, or out of date; the 1.5× rule was an approximation rule of thumb, that worked when ram was a certain size. If you do not hibernate and have 12Gb then you probably don't need swap. I have 8Gb ram and 8Gb swap (more than I need). My machine rarely swaps, and because ½ of ram will usually just be disk cache, this can be dropped. If I have used to much ram, e.g. virtualbox, then I could save, and exit the virtual machine first.

Comment: I thing in principle you could have a pool of swap partitions( even create them on the fly for the size that you need, from a spare region of disk ), and add them `swapon` as needed. But you will have to be **very**, **very**, **very** careful not to trash a swap that has a hibernation on it. (Warning you will lose data if you do this. As you will make a mistake one day.)

Comment: Well to be more specific, I really only want to hibernate on one of the os. rhel is for work, kali is for studying pentesting, and the other (mint) is for everyday use. I always log off kali/rhel when I'm done with what I was doing, but I would like it to go into hibernation mode when I close the lid on my laptop while using mint. Hope this helps. I think I really only need 1 swap partition, but I'm not sure how big it should be, this is the first time I've had so much ram. Usually I only had 4 or 6gb of ram so I set my swap to be equal to my ram. Having a 12gb+ swap seems overkill

Comment: I just want to make sure my swap is big enough to allow hibernation on mint. Also, I still am wondering if I will need a separate boot partition for rhel since it uses a different filesystem